# string does not display as html in erb

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, tags, erb

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I have a string which is a snippet of HTML. I am using the <%= %> erb tags to have it displayed. However, it does not render it as a HTML. It is stripping the tags and inserting characters

The source ERB snippet can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/alaghu/e7d8b7fe66b9ebea224a#file-erb_not_rendering_html-erb)

The html tags seems to be stripped , but instead is replaces with  comes out as  "& lt span class=&# x27;" . The source can be  seen [here](https://gist.github.com/alaghu/65d18740fa2f3ae7024e#file-html_source-html)

Comment: Try using either `html_safe` or `raw`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i said, try using either `html_safe` or `raw`

```
<%= sent_array.join('').html_safe %>
```

**OR**

```
<%= raw sent_array.join('') %>
```

**OR**

```
<%== sent_array.join('') %>
```

`<%==` is equivalent to `raw`

For more details,see these **[Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#output-safety)**. In your case,you can also refer to **[safe_join](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper/safe_join)**

Comment: Hi Pavan,Thank you for providing me these details. I will test this out later today.

Comment: Thank you very much Pavan. I used html_Safe and worked.